# Converting MOQ setup code to vb.net from c#

Tags: vb.net-2010, c#-to-vb.net

I have a expression og MOQ (lambda/linq) in c#. When tried to conevert and use this code in vb.net, I am getting an error

**C# code**

```
_dataLayerMock.Setup(x => x.SaveAccount(It.Is<Account>(a => a.AccountType == AccountType.Private)));
```

**Converted VB.net code**

```
_dataLayerMock.Setup(Function(x) x.SaveAccount(It.[Is](Of Account)(Function(a) a.AccountType = AccountType.[Private])))
```

**Error**

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Setup' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Function Setup(Of TResult)(expression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of ConsoleApplication1.IDataLayer, TResult))) As Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup(Of ConsoleApplication1.IDataLayer, TResult)': Expression does not produce a value.
    'Public Function Setup(Of TResult)(expression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of ConsoleApplication1.IDataLayer, TResult))) As Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup(Of ConsoleApplication1.IDataLayer, TResult)': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
    'Public Function Setup(expression As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Action(Of ConsoleApplication1.IDataLayer))) As Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup(Of ConsoleApplication1.IDataLayer)': Expression does not produce a value. D:\Araamudhan\Project\Amex\Maven-NPanday\Application\ClassLibrary\LinqTest\LinqTest\BusinessLayerTest.vb    20  9   LinqTest
```

Could anyone help me out how to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the code converter(s) - they come in handy are great for these instances.
http://converter.telerik.com/

```
_dataLayerMock.Setup(Function(x) x.SaveAccount(It.[Is](Function(a) a.AccountType = AccountType.[Private])))
```

HTH

Comment: Getting the same error. This converter also gives me the same code.

Comment: Please check your code, whether you are passing the correct parameter for the Setup method. Not too much familiar with MOQ, With the information provided, it looks like you are calling a method while setting up  ...                                            "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Setup' can be called with these arguments"

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need this answered anymore but in case someone else comes across this question.

I believe this does not work in VB.net because lambdas must return a value in vb and so will not allow you to mock a sub method in VB.

Hope this helps